# PHP Doc not working on Mac OS Sierra

Tags: php, pear, macos-sierra, phpdoc

This is my configuration for pear and I will get this error while I'm executing php doc command. Im on Mac OS Sierra and my php -v is PHP 5.6.30 (cli) (built: Feb  7 2017 16:18:37)

```
phpdoc --filename first-doc.php -t docs
PHP Warning:  require(PhpDocumentor/phpDocumentor/phpdoc.inc): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/local/bin/phpdoc on line 40
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'PhpDocumentor/phpDocumentor/phpdoc.inc' (include_path='.:') in /usr/local/bin/phpdoc on line 40
```

[image]
Please help

Comment: It's clearly saying this file `phpdoc` does not exist in this path `/usr/local/bin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a minimum, your PHP configuration's `include_path` does not contain the main PEAR `php_dir` location.

Note the error message shows `(include_path='.:')`, meaning it only contains your current directory you're in right now in the shell.

Your PEAR config shows that `php_dir` is set to `/usr/lib/php`, so that needs to be added to the `include_path` setting in your `php.ini` file.

I'm actually surprised that PEAR would install anything successfully without the include_path set correctly, as the PEAR program itself should be having trouble running itself.  Perhaps the include_path was misconfigured *after* things were installed.